# Add constructors to auto-generated OpenAPI service client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, webapi

I've got a Blazor WebAssembly project with an ASP.NET WebAPI hosted service. If I use the auto-generated code in the "Connected Services" in Visual Studio to retrieve the OpenAPI definition, I get a nice proxy representing all of the HTTP endpoints, complete with request and reply objects.

But the generated request/reply classes have only a default constructor and properties, like:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.0.22.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.0.0)")]
public partial class GetDetailedMessageRequest 
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("id", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public long Id { get; set; }


}
```

I prefer to have at least the option of a constructor with each of the properties - this is actually the way the classes are in the service side:

```
public class GetDetailedMessageRequest
{
    public GetDetailedMessageRequest() { }

    public GetDetailedMessageRequest(long id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to either have the code generator build these constructors, or tell it not to create the model classes at all, and instead let both the client reference the shared models project?

Neither of these seems likely - I can think of a couple workarounds, like manually editing the generated code, or creating the request on the client using the class from my shared project, serializing it, deserializing it into the generated class type, or possibly just building the constructors again in new partial classes for all of these...But obviously those are not ideal.

I could always build my own code generator, or skip the generated stuff altogether and just use HttpClient normally - but I like the idea of an auto-generated proxy class.

Comment: `Is there any way to either have the code generator build these constructors, or tell it not to create the model classes at all, and instead let both the client reference the shared models project?` I'm afraid not.